# Angular Datepicker gives bad dates

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui

I have this datepicker -> http://jsfiddle.net/maralik/zbf4q8Ld/1/

And when I select a date I'm getting bad date. Where is a problem? There is nothing else, just the datepicker and I still get bad dates

```
app = angular.module 'myapp', ['ng-bootstrap-datepicker']

 AppCtrl = ($scope)->
   $scope.datepickerOptions =
     format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
     language: 'cs'
     autoclose: true
     weekStart: 0

  $scope.date = '2015-06-22'

app.controller 'AppCtrl', AppCtrl    
angular.bootstrap document, ['myapp']
```

What I'm getting you can see here -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzc9ZSGdiL-teGtsMkhLSGU0R3c/view?usp=sharing

Any idea? It would really help me a lot

Thanks!

David

Comment: The directive you are using has the same error. Also they said only component type is supported.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't undestand - so how can I fix it? Use another version? Use totaly another component like Angular Strap or?

Answer (score 0):

That's really odd. I tried many different options on your example and still not working as it should.
Maybe you should try 'ui.bootstrap'. It also has datepicker and it works properly. Here's an example. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s54es2jj/2/)

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.opened = true;
  $scope.openStartDatepicker = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    startingDay: 1
  };
});
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

Comment: Well yes, I just want to use the Angular-UI because we use more stuff in here from angular-ui..